# How to combine the attributes from Different ExecuteScript Processor and add them in UpdateAttribute in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a usecase to run different scripts(ExecuteScript Processor)based on different config sets as (ex : AB - ExecuteScriptAB, AC -ExecuteScriptAC , AL - ExecuteScriptAL, AM - ExecuteScriptAM)

Inside each ExecuteScript Processor, I have used `session.putAttribute()`  using python script to get the execute status code of all scripts.

`For AB : flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"returnCodeAB",str(exec_code));`

`For AC : flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"returnCodeAC",str(exec_code));`

`For AL : flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"returnCodeAL",str(exec_code));`

`For AM : flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"returnCodeAM",str(exec_code));`

Now, I want to **add all the values of these 4 attributes** i.e `returnCodeAB`+`returnCodeAC`+`returnCodeAL`+`returnCodeAM` and return a **final status code value**. As these scripts execute seperately , i am unable to merge them and add the values .. they act as different processors.

I tried to use UpdateAttribute Processor after these scripts and create and attribute in Advanced Tab but it did not help. Can someone help me with efficient solution?

Comment: Add an example, please. Do you have one FlowFile with 4 attributes?

Comment: There are 4 different FlowFiles (each file from each ExecuteScript)